# Informix equivalent to Oracle's UPDATE ... RETURNING INTO statement

Tags: sql, oracle, informix

In Oracle I can return information from an UPDATE statement like so:

```
UPDATE SOME_TABLE
SET SOME_COL = SYSDATE
WHERE
    ...
RETURNING SOME_COL INTO :OutParameter
```

Combined with the number of affected rows this allows to check whether a row exists, update it, then return some information about the updated row (like the newly updated value, or the row id, or whatever), all in one query.

This can also be accomplished in SQL Server using the OUTPUT clause.

**Is there anything like this in Informix?** I've checked Informix's [UPDATE syntax](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/topic/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls864.htm) and 
it doesn't look like it has anything equivalent... Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of affected rows is available from the SQLCA record, which is available in plain SQL or SPL via `DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd2')`

e.g.:

```
UPDATE table SET foo = 'bar' WHERE baz = 'quux';
INSERT INTO log_table (date_stamp, msg, row_count)
  VALUES (CURRENT, "Updated foo to bar", DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd2'));
```

See the [fine manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1488.htm).

There's no equivalent to the `RETURNING` clause in Informix. The concept seems odd to me - how would that work when multiple rows have been updated, with dynamic content, like `SET foo = baz * bar` where foo, baz and bar are all columns, and there's no single value shared by all affected tuples?

Comment: You can use the `RETURNING` clause with the values going into a collection so that multiple rows can be captured at once.

Comment: Expanding on Adam's remark, the very usefulness of the RETURNING clause is so that your UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE statement returns information about the modified row(s). In your example you could add RETURNING foo INTO :F to have it output the final value of foo after multiplying baz * bar. This will work with values altered by sequencers, randomizers, triggers, functions, etc.

Comment: Anyways, I've accepted your "There's no equivalent to the RETURNING clause in Informix" answer.